# How to disable code highlighting for google code prettify?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pretty-print, google-code-prettify

Is it possible to add a class to pre tag to disable code highlight? I tried adding classes prettyprint-false and no-prettyprint. 
https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 3):

```
<pre class="prettyprint prettyprinted">
```

Or within a pretty-printed block, add this to a section you don't want prettified:

```
<span class="nocode"> ... </span>
```

Example of a prettyprinted block with a "nocode" section:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
   select blah
   from   blahblah
   where  blahblahblah;

   <span class="nocode">
   BLAH
   ------------
   Various results
   of clever query

   2 rows selected.
   </span>
</pre>
```